# Angular JS ng-class or ng-if use

Tags: php, angularjs, ng-class

How I do following Code in angular JS

```
// PHP Code 
<?php foreach($data as $key=>$row) { 
 if($key%2 == 0) { ?>
    <div class="col 3"> Run this 
    <ul>
<?php } ?>
    <li> Some Data </li>

  <?php if($key%2 == 1) { ?>
    </ul></div>
   <?php } } ?>
```

I want to run above code in angular JS. any help appreciated.

Comment: Provide some example of what you've tried so far.

Comment: nothing did not understand it yet i tried to use ng-class

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
<div ng-repeat="key in data">
<div ng-if="(key%2 == 0)" class="col 3"> Run this 
    <ul>
    <li> Some Data </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div ng-if="(key%2 == 1)"> Run this 
    <ul>
    <li> Some Data </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: i want to run when key is 0 these class="col 3" <ul> and when key is 1 then close the </div> and </ul>